# Trying to get Windows VPN working

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, vpn

I have a Windows 7 (desktop) which should be VPN server and a windows 8.1 (laptop) which 
should be client.

...

- I have found out my Win7 computers local IP address.
- I have found out my public IP address by visiting a website that tells me my IP
  addreess.
- My laptop is connected through wifi over mobile, so it does
  not share same internet/network with desktop which has a cabled
  internet connection.

...

So I have setup my router to forward all requests on VPN port number to my desktop:
[image]

These are the ports sofar I have read could be important for L2TP and PPTP

[image]

...

In Windows 7 Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
I choose "File | New Incoming Connection"
[image]

In this dialog I created another account(?)
called "vpnuser" with password "vpnpass".

After having done so, Windows reports success and tells me I will
need the computer name information which it shows, i.e. "namexample".
I am not actually sure if I actually need this or not anywhere.

...

I then try connect from Windows 8 - but this with error
"800" where it states the tunnel was unreachable.

...

I then go back and see I in Win7 and Win8 can edit properties and e.g. choose encryption/handshake type.

And there is also something called predefined key... But that is slightly confusing since I have not had the opportunity to configure a preshared key.

The current situation is hat I have not been able to get any VPN configuration I have tried working - I guess / hope it is because I have tried the wrong combinations somehow

...

Can anyone suggest a guide I can use? One that tells:

1. What to forward in router
2. What to enable in Windows Firewall
3. What settings to use (defaults appear not to be working)

I would prefer a setting that is reasonable secure (L2TP? But what protocols/handshake can I allow on it?

I need something that I can follow and which *will* work if done correctly. Then I can try take my laptop to a friend's and check from a cabled internet instead of WIFI over mobile.

Comment: Does the Windows 7 "Server" have the Windows firewall enabled on it?

Comment: Windows to my knowlege does not have a built-in VPN server capability.  It sounds like you should setup a OpenVPN server then connect to that.

Comment: @Ramhound Win7 and Win8 have built-in VPN server support. Ton of Google results, e.g. www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

Comment: @byachna Yes. but I have not received any warnings or anything. But I will try look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get this error if the subnet is the same on both ends.
I.E both local network (that you are connecting from) and remote network (that you are trying to connect to via VPN) has the same subnet like: 192.168.1.xxx
Therefore, it is a good idea NOT to use 192.168.1.xxx on your business network which you will be VPNing to.

If the problem persists follow this :

1) Ping the VPN server to ensure it is available.

2) Confirm your computer's/Router's firewall settings are still configured to permit traffic to and from your VPN. If you are using PPTP protocol, TCP Port 1723 and GRE Protocol 47 must be opened/enabled and for L2TP ensure UDP port 1701 is not blocked.

3) Confirm that the firewall settings will allow traffic on UDP ports 500 and 4500 if using IKEv2 for the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Could the problem be caused by my laptop connecting to the internet through using Android WIFI? I will try change the 192.168.1.xxx on our business network. (I have tried pnging and forward everything. I have not received any FireWall warnings, but will try go over it again.) I have also expanded my initial post.

Comment: Accepted answer although I have problems configuring router/firewall - see: https://superuser.com/questions/759662/vpn-and-getting-router-firwall-configuration-correct